# How to rename a Child in Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an Android chat application using Firebase as its back end. When a user updates his/her details after somedays, I want to update the name of the child in `Message` node according to the updated name.

[image]

I want to Update the children names when users update there user names from the app. For example, how can I change the Child name `PBW` from the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
Firebase ref = Firebase(url: "https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
Firebase userRef = ref.child(YOUR_NODE);
Map newUserData = new HashMap();
newUserData.put(YOUR_NEW_DATA);

userRef.updateChildren(newUserData);
```

Comment: Don't forget to also remove the old child.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is create another child and move data

```
databaseReference.child(**oldChildName**).get().addOnSuccessListener(dataSnapshot -> {
                            databaseReference.child(**newChildName**).setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                            databaseReference.child(**oldChildName**).removeValue();
                        });
```